# How does Facebook determine who to suggest to add to a group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I've recently created a group on Facebook. Subsequently when I insert my cursor to the search box to insert new people a dropdown comes in and proposes some people. Are those people proposed because they showed some interest on my group or is it because I spoke to them recently? Which is the criteria of these suggesting people?

Answer (score 1):

It is up to engine's logic. And no one will tell you exactly how it works, because that's company's policy. I think there a lot factors included. You can start read about machine learning.